# How can I stop executing .wlua files?

Tags: lua

Is it possible to force stop a .wlua file? I figured that I would have to use the Lua Command Line to do this, but I can't seem to find out how to stop them.

If it's possible, how can it be done?

Comment: It's extension used on Windows to distinguish standalone gui applications which should be run by wlua.exe (hiding the console) from normal scripts. Inside they are perfectly the same.

Answer (score 4):

Because `wlua.exe` doesn't open the console window (that's the purpose) and you can't send Ctrl-C, the only way to terminate such application is to use Processes window in Task Manager. Note, however, that the process name will be `wlua.exe` for every file opened that way.

Of course, it's meant only to be used when the application isn't responding. Your GUI application should provide a way to close it, such as close button, listening for ESC key etc.